# PostgreSQL - Refractoring a monster of a Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have somehow hit my record of the largest query i have made to this date, luckily its quite well structured... but it really is ugly, i do wonder if there's any way i could refractor it with a bit of knowledge from the community, it would be much appreciated!

Here's the monster with an execution time of 5ms within a 10 row table

```
SELECT
q.frontend AS platform,
r.frontend AS library,

CONCAT( -- Image Reference eg. px_iej1k321foa8_0
    CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.prefix
        ELSE (SELECT prefix FROM files.platform a WHERE a.platform = 'local') END,
    '_', CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN p.reference ELSE p.file_name END,
    CASE WHEN (
        (SELECT real_choice FROM -- Image Count
            (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.choice ASC)
            AS real_choice FROM files.main b
            WHERE b.platform = p.platform AND b.reference = p.reference
        ) c WHERE c.id = p.id)::integer) = 1 THEN '' ELSE CONCAT('_', p.choice)
    END
) AS reference,

CONCAT( -- Image Directory
    'https://',
    CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.temp_bucket ELSE q.bucket END,
    '/', t.path, '/', p.file_name, '.', s.name
) AS directory,


CASE WHEN u.path IS NOT NULL AND w.name IS NOT NULL THEN
CONCAT( -- Image Thumbnail
    'https://',
    CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.temp_bucket ELSE q.bucket END,
    '/', u.path, '/', p.file_name, '.', w.name
) END AS thumbnail,

CONCAT(q.file_source_path, p.reference) AS source, -- Image Original Source
v.frontend AS rating,

(SELECT real_choice FROM -- Image Count
(SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.choice ASC)
    AS real_choice FROM files.main b
    WHERE b.platform = p.platform AND b.reference = p.reference
) c WHERE c.id = p.id)::integer AS choice,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files.main b -- Image Total Count
    WHERE b.platform = p.platform
    AND b.reference = p.reference
)::integer AS total_choices

FROM files.main p
LEFT JOIN files.platform q
ON p.platform = q.id
LEFT JOIN files.library r
ON p.library = r.id
LEFT JOIN files.extension s
ON p.extension = s.id
LEFT JOIN files.path t
ON p.path = t.id
LEFT JOIN files.path u
ON p.path_thumbnail = u.id
LEFT JOIN files.rating v
ON p.rating = v.id
LEFT JOIN files.extension w
ON p.extension_thumbnail = w.id
WHERE p.id = $1;
```

Whereas $1 represents an integer (at very bottom)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, I'd start with formatting.

```
SELECT
  q.frontend AS platform,
  r.frontend AS library,

  CONCAT( -- Image Reference eg. px_iej1k321foa8_0
      CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.prefix
          ELSE (SELECT prefix FROM files.platform a WHERE a.platform = 'local') 
  END,
      '_', CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN p.reference ELSE p.file_name END,
      CASE WHEN (
          (SELECT real_choice FROM -- Image Count
              (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.choice ASC)
              AS real_choice FROM files.main b
              WHERE b.platform = p.platform AND b.reference = p.reference
          ) c WHERE c.id = p.id)::integer) = 1 THEN '' ELSE CONCAT('_', p.choice)
      END
  ) AS reference,

  CONCAT( -- Image Directory
      'https://',
      CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.temp_bucket ELSE q.bucket END,
      '/', t.path, '/', p.file_name, '.', s.name
  ) AS directory,


  CASE WHEN u.path IS NOT NULL AND w.name IS NOT NULL THEN
  CONCAT( -- Image Thumbnail
      'https://',
      CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.temp_bucket ELSE q.bucket END,
      '/', u.path, '/', p.file_name, '.', w.name
  ) END AS thumbnail,

  CONCAT(q.file_source_path, p.reference) AS source, -- Image Original Source
  v.frontend AS rating,

  (SELECT real_choice FROM -- Image Count
    (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.choice ASC)
        AS real_choice FROM files.main b
        WHERE b.platform = p.platform AND b.reference = p.reference
    ) c WHERE c.id = p.id)::integer AS choice,

  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files.main b -- Image Total Count
      WHERE b.platform = p.platform
      AND b.reference = p.reference
  )::integer AS total_choices

FROM files.main p
LEFT JOIN files.platform q ON p.platform = q.id
LEFT JOIN files.library r ON p.library = r.id
LEFT JOIN files.extension s ON p.extension = s.id
LEFT JOIN files.path t ON p.path = t.id
LEFT JOIN files.path u ON p.path_thumbnail = u.id
LEFT JOIN files.rating v ON p.rating = v.id
LEFT JOIN files.extension w ON p.extension_thumbnail = w.id
WHERE p.id = $1;
```

It's a little shorter and easier to read already.

Next is take any expressions in the `select` clause which are not dependent on much else in the query and move them into a CTE.

```
WITH image_count AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)::integer c AS total_choices,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.choice ASC) AS real_choice
  FROM files.main p
  INNER JOIN files.main b ON b.platform = p.platform AND b.reference = p.reference
  WHERE p.id = $1
)
SELECT
  q.frontend AS platform,
  r.frontend AS library,

  CONCAT( -- Image Reference eg. px_iej1k321foa8_0
      CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.prefix
          ELSE (SELECT prefix FROM files.platform a WHERE a.platform = 'local') 
  END,
      '_', CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN p.reference ELSE p.file_name END,
      CASE WHEN (image_count.real_choice::integer) = 1 THEN '' ELSE CONCAT('_', p.choice)
      END
  ) AS reference,

  CONCAT( -- Image Directory
      'https://',
      CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.temp_bucket ELSE q.bucket END,
      '/', t.path, '/', p.file_name, '.', s.name
  ) AS directory,

  CASE WHEN u.path IS NOT NULL AND w.name IS NOT NULL THEN
  CONCAT( -- Image Thumbnail
      'https://',
      CASE WHEN p.is_temporary THEN q.temp_bucket ELSE q.bucket END,
      '/', u.path, '/', p.file_name, '.', w.name
  ) END AS thumbnail,

  CONCAT(q.file_source_path, p.reference) AS source, -- Image Original Source
  v.frontend AS rating,

  total_image_count.real_choice, -- Image Count
  total_image_count.total_choices -- Image Total Count

FROM files.main p
LEFT JOIN files.platform q ON p.platform = q.id
LEFT JOIN files.library r ON p.library = r.id
LEFT JOIN files.extension s ON p.extension = s.id
LEFT JOIN files.path t ON p.path = t.id
LEFT JOIN files.path u ON p.path_thumbnail = u.id
LEFT JOIN files.rating v ON p.rating = v.id
LEFT JOIN files.extension w ON p.extension_thumbnail = w.id
CROSS JOIN total_image_count
WHERE p.id = $1;
```

Now personally, I'd probably leave it there.  It's not hard to read to me, but of course that is subjective.

If I were to take it a step further, I might look into who is calling the query and see if the caller is in a position to take some of the string manipulation logic.  Most of the remaining complexity is just case statements and string concats, which could potentially be handled by the application that calls this, if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using temporary tables in a transaction block to create intermediate results instead of giant, complex sql statements.  They are much easier to read and maintain.
Here is the general idea:

```
Start transaction block
Create Temp table with just needed columns
Sql statement to perform joins into table (repeat as needed)
Sql statement to perform conversions
Sql statement to move results to permanent location
Commit (end of transaction)
```

The commit block ensures that it behaves the same as a single statement (make sure autocommit is turned off).  Using this method allows you to break the problem into logical pieces that are easier to read and modify.  You'll take a tiny hit in efficiency, but it will allow you to tackle the most complex problems

Comment: is those the same as materialized view? i still need to run the query for that view